# Interior shear wall or ugly duckling?

Tags: walls, shear

I’d like to put a small 2’ x4’ opening next to the stairs but found what appears to be a shear wall. I’m planning to reinforce it with a framing around the opening but now question this decision in fear of compromising the wall integrity. [image]

Comment: It would help if you indicated on the pic, where you intend to put the opening.

Comment: What is on the other side of that wall to the left in the picture? And what's above that area? I ask because it looks load bearing to me; it looks like joists and blocking above it.

Comment: 2'×4' is pretty big for a shear wall opening, where that wall looks suspicious. Was the area on the other side of the wall possibly added on after the house's initial construction? Do you live in a high seismicity region? You might be surprised. There's a tiny little patch of Missouri, for instance, with high seismicity. Is the house pretty long measured perpendicular to that wall? "Pretty long" being 60 ft?

Comment: Based on your removed material, it looks like you're orienting this opening with the 4 ft dimension vertical at the end of the wall. Is that the case? If there's room between the stairs and your opening, you might trim the other side's plywood thickness off the width of a couple of wall studs and add a a 2 ft width chunk of plywood. As long as removing the 2 ft from the shear wall's end doesn't violate an aspect ratio constraint from the SDPWS, the new plywood should make up for the loss from your opening. If you're a by-the-book person, anyway.

Comment: That’s correct. Plan was to add an additional stud in each side of the opened plywood along with a header. It looks like the plywood continues throughout the length of the staircase.

Comment: The shear wall extends left beyond the staircase about 10 feet. Above is the second story of the house and a dining room on the other side. Thus is a track home and there are a few others in the block with a similar layout. Some have the entire staircase open. I live in California so earthquakes are a concern.

Comment: The perpendicular length of the house is about 20 ft. Technically it’s the short side of a rectangular shape of a two story house. That area looks sketchy on the other side there is added duct work and studs that basically wobbled and installed from scrap wood after the build. This was initially opened after a leak from the upstairs toilet poured into the dining room on the other side. Sounds like closing in the shear wall is the most conservative approach without major cost and modification to that area. Bummer

Comment: The total width of the house is 20 ft, so there are two parallel exterior walls spaced 20 ft apart? This shear wall candidate splits that 20 ft width? And the other dimension is pretty long, as in there was lots of space for shear panels in the parallel exterior walls? Your shear wall candidate is strange if it is a shear wall. Even in earthquake areas, the distance between your walls would be at least 25 ft (under the IRC) before an internal shear wall becomes necessary. Are there a ton of holes in one of the parallel exterior walls, maybe, that could rationalize an internal shear wall?

Comment: I'm curious, but at this point pushing further is probably a waste of time. Paneling the other side to compensate is probably the limit of responsible advice without looking in person. And insurance. The person who tells you to disassemble part of a shear wall candidate should have insurance.

Comment: There are doors that lead to the back yard on the back wall of the house. Front of the house has a door and two windows. This wall is along the staircase smack in the middle of the house. I did see a plate in the joists so at this point I’m wondering if the previous owner did some off permit retrofitting after Northridge quake. No reputable contractor would do such a sloppy job.

Comment: You can check on your seismic category at [IRC R301.2.2.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR301.2.2.1). You could be in seismic design category E, where the IRC doesn't cover category E. If that's the case, then I definitely wouldn't cut any corners.

Comment: Had an earthquake today and one last week. I think I’ll keep the wall intact.